# CORS works except when custom header is set on client

Tags: java, cors, jooby

#### Config

**Jooby Version**: 2.13.0
**Using Undertow**
**JDK 17**

My setup of CORS works as expected (with only 1 exception) with the config below:

```
Cors cors = new Cors().setMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
cors.allowOrigin("*");
cors.setExposedHeaders("RT");
cors.setUseCredentials(true);
decorator(new CorsHandler(cors));
```

The problem appears when I set a custom header on the client.  Suddenly I see the message with error code 403:

**Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:9801/test. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).**

Help please....

Comment: Which custom header are you setting on the request? Please include all the relevant information (but no more than that) to your question; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you look at the code above you can see I am setting **RT** as a custom header. I am using it to track a session variable.

Basically from my API the header **RT** is set and is sent as part of the response.

I want to send this value back to the server by setting it on the response.  But whenever I do, the request fails first from **OPTIONS** and then the **POST** fails as well for similar reason.

Comment: All your code shows is that, in your CORS config, you're _exposing_ a _response_ header named `RT` to client code. Perhaps you're confusing `setExposedHeaders` with `setAllowedHeaders`...

Comment: I do not see the method `setAllowedHeaders`.  But there is `setHeaders`.  Here I added **RT** and (re-added) the default headers and it seemed to work.

Do you know when to use ExposedHeaders?

Thanks

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion I investigated and found that if I used the `Cors.setHeader()` that I was able to get my requests working as expected.

There maybe other solutions but this worked for me.

Please note that the method is not accretive, meaning that you have to add the default headers like `Origin` and `Accept`, otherwise your single header will be the only one.